# Can't run the monkeyrunner script

Tags: java, android, android-studio, terminal

I want to do some test with monkeyrunner but it can't work, so I run the monkeyrunner in the terminal and got error like

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib:/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64 is not supported. Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I found the path /86_64 and I think that right, so what's wrong with that and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

`monkeyrunner` doesn't work with the latest java, you have to use java 8

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html